# Insert JavaScript variable in Django tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I'm working on an app that uses Django and jQuery for various things. I'm trying to assemble an AJAX request with jQuery that requires that I use Django's {% url %} template function. One of the arguments needed for the url call is stored in a JavaScript variable. Is it possible to insert the value of the JS var into the {% url %} tag? Something like

```
var jsvar = somestuff;
{% url some.view arg1=jsvar %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Pass a sentinel (e.g. `%s`) to `url` which you replace in JavaScript with the actual value.